# How do i add my ta indicator to my mplfinance candlstick chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-ta

I do apologize for this question but I am seriously struggling. Below is my code so far. Im 2 months into python and here Ive been sitting for a whole day trying to figure this out. Please can someone take a look and maybe provide a comment on it.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aah4KDMIBLtNVHXwvEeW0TDKMdBL2tvz?usp=sharing

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlGe4.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of [**mplfinance tutorials listed here**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#contents-and-tutorials).

Recommend you read the **[Adding Your Own Technical Studies to Plots](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb)** tutorial.

The basic idea is to call `mpf.make_addplot()` to generate the information needed to display your TA on the candlestick chart, and then use kwarg `addplot` to add it to the candelstick chart.  Something like this:

```py
ap = mpf.make_addplot( ta_data, kwargs, ... )

mpf.plot( df, type='candle', addplot=ap )
```

...

---

P.S.  I am not very familiar with `pandas_ta`, but i do know that it uses mplfinance under the hood, and there should be, I believe, a way to simply ask `pandas_ta` to plot both your candlestick chart and the technical analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code in your question, I see that the error is at the end where the indicator is added with plotly, so I will also add a graph using plotly as an example.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=df.index,
                             open=df['Open'],
                             high=df['High'],
                             low=df['Low'],
                             close=df['Close'],
                             name='EURUSD=X'
                             ))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                         y=df['Final Lowerband'],
                         mode='lines',
                         line=dict(color='green'),
                         name='Final Lowerband'
                         ))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                         y=df['Final Upperband'],
                         mode='lines',
                         line=dict(color='red'),
                         name='Final Upperband'
                         ))

fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: OMG thank you so much. You are a life saver. I will study how you did because damn, it sucks not knowing what im doing. Really appreciate your help.